# declare a static array as pointer in c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Here are a few lines of C++ code I recently saw.

```
double a[p][p];
for(i=0;i<p;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<p;j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = m[i][j]; //m is sth we are given.
    }
}
dgeev_(&jobvl,&jobvr,&p,(double*)a,&lda,(double*)wr,(double*)wi,(double*)vl,
      &ldvl,(double*)vr,&ldvr,(double*)work,&lwork,&info);
// sth else..
```

`dgeev_` is a function and you can find its documentation here:
http://www.netlib.org/clapack/old/double/dgeev.c

`dgeev_` is declared in header in the following way, so we can use C function in C++ codes.

```
extern "C" {
void dgeev_(char*, char*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*,
 int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*);
}
```

As we can see, `a` is static array, and `dgeev_` need a variable of type `doublereal *` for the 4th parameter.

What does `(double*)a` do here?

Comment: It's casting. You should have a good C or C++ reference on hand if this is baffling. It's an unusually long method signature, but it's not too crazy in terms of structure.

Comment: This is not C++ code. It's C. Both in style and in reality. Look at the file extension.

Comment: Passing `a` to a function will decay the array to a pointer to its first element, so the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, because `a` is two-dimensional. The cast is not only "necessary" to obtain a build; it is wrong.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition This is actually C++ code.  We can call `dgeev_` since it is declared in the header file: `extern "C" {
 void dpotri_(char*,int*,double*,int*,int*);
 void dgeev_(char*, char*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*,
  int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*);
}
` Sorry I forgot to mention this.

Comment: @W.Yang: Then why is the file called `dgeev.c`? C++ code is not written in files named `.c`. Furthermore, [the project's own FAQ says that it is C code](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/old/faq.html). So I'm not sure why you're claiming that it is C++.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition You are right that `dgeev.c` is C. But the snippets of codes I provided is C++. By declaring the C function `extern "C"` (in the C++ code), so we can use C directly in C++. I think this may be important for this question.

Comment: @W.Yang: Ah right, yes okay. Then this is even worse since C++ does not support VLAs.

Comment: *dgeev_ is a function and you can find its documentation here:* Link is to source!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition `p` could be a initialized `const`, but then again passing &p to `dgeev_` would be wrong.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya `p` is an integer. Why would passing `&p` to `dgeev_` be wrong?

Comment: @W.Yang I mentioned that `p` *could* be `const int` since it is used to create an array (and c++ does not have VLA). In that case &p cannot be passed to `dgeev_`

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, I'm afraid it is not C, as C doesn't admit the `extern "C" { ... }` construction.  I suppose it is C++, but using a **C** language function.  This is a supported thing in **C++** and by no means, makes your comment appropiate.  What dialect of **C++** do you use that makes you thing this is plain **C** ???  (the problem is not on the `dgeev_` function, but in the interface to it from **C++**)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, again you are wrong.  VLA _is supported_ in **C++** as it is in **C**,  but argument type checking cannot be done and you are warned as a discouraged feature of the language.  It was included for **C** compatibility purposes.  Has the PO question irritated you by some reason?  What's the purpose of your flames?  If you are not going to provide support, please, be quiet and don't flame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either a mistake or the author is playing a trick on you.

He's used a C-style cast to "hack" the value `a` into the `double*` type, so that a two-dimensional array may be treated as a single-dimensional array. ([`doublereal` is just an alias for `double`](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/old/util/f2c.h).)

Problem is, `a` *isn't* a `double*`, nor is it actually convertible to a `double*`. I don't know what it *is* convertible to, since VLAs are only available in C++ as a GCC extension; there is no standard wording to consult. I'm going to just conclude that this program has undefined behaviour (though it probably appears to work, due to how these things are practically laid out in memory).

If the author wants to be able to safely read this array using single-dimension indices, he should have declared it that way to begin with (optionally providing the *illusion* of 2D indexes on top of the data store).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143356/discussion-on-answer-by-boundaryimposition-declare-a-static-array-as-pointer-in).